# moving CGPoint a certain distance along a certain heading...iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, trigonometry, heading, cgpoint

this seems like such a simple problem but I have been unable to find an answer (and im no good at math). I am trying to move a UIView to a new CGPoint X distance away along a certain heading. What is the formula for determining the new coordinates?

(i do no want this to be animated, just an instantaneous move)

something like:

```
x = 100; (current x value)
y = 150; (current y value)
d = 25; (distance to move the point)
h = 90; (west)

\\\ insert formula to determine new x,y coords

self.car.center =  (CGPointMake ([newX],[newY]);
```

Comment: What does "certain heading" mean? Is that a direction? Any assumptions about this? Some datatypes and code snippets would help.

Comment: sorry i dont even have an code yet, im just kind of getting started on this. what i mean by heading is a course along a cardinal direction. I have a UIView on a map that needs to be moved as if it were following a heading (360 degrees).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If **p** is your point, D is the distance, and θ is the heading-angle from the X-axis,

> **p**<sub>new</sub>.x = **p**<sub>old</sub>.x + D * cos(θ)
>   **p**<sub>new</sub>.y = **p**<sub>old</sub>.y + D * sin(θ)

Rather than storing distances and angles, though, this is usually done using [vectors](http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1150/03Vct2D/Vectrs.html) (which removes the need for the sin/cos)

Comment: Additionally, don't forget to convert the angle to radians.